# why an element is posted eventhough its unchecked?

Tags: php, ajax, post, checkbox, yii

I am using Yii, I want to to submit a form to an action. in the action I get that a checkbox is posted eventhough I didn't checked it, and the value of it is 1 always, here is my code:

```
    <?php echo CHtml::beginForm(Yii::app()->createUrl('jobs/index2'), 'POST'); ?>
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3 blog-sidebar" >

              <div class="sidebar-module">

                <h4 style="color:#D11F45">Refine your search</h4>

        <h4>Division</h4>
        <div id="Division">
            <?php 
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($model2 as $m2){
            if($m2['category']==('Division')){
                echo '<div class="checkbox"><label>'.
                        CHtml::checkBox("c".$i, false).$m2->tag

            .'</label></div>';
                $i++;
            }

                        }
                ?>
            </div>

            <hr>

             <h4>Location</h4>
             <div id="Location">
                <?php 

                foreach ($model2 as $m2){

                    if($m2['category']=='Location'){
                    echo '<div class="checkbox"><label>'.
                            CHtml::checkBox("c".$i, false, array('value'=>'hhhhhhhhhhh', 'uncheckValue'=>'N')).$m2->tag

                        .'</label></div>';
                    $i++;}
                }
                ?>
             </div>

            <hr>


            <?php

            echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(

                        'Search',
                        array('jobs/index2'),
                        array(
                            'update'=>'#jobslist',
                        )
                    );


            ?>
                      </div>
                  </div><!-- /.blog-sidebar -->

<?php  echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-lg-9 blog-main" id="jobslist">

          <?php echo $this->renderPartial('_index', array('model'=>$model)); ?>  
        </div>
      </div>    
    </div>
    </div>
<script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/j.js"></script>
```

browser source:

```
<div class="span-19">
    <div id="content">



      <div class="row" style="border-top:thin #333 solid">


            <img src="/Patra/images/job-banner.jpg" width="100%">      


    </div>

                  <form action="/Patra/index.php/jobs/index2" method="POST">    <div class="row">


    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3 blog-sidebar">

          <div class="sidebar-module">

            <h4 style="color:#D11F45">Refine your search</h4>

            <h4>Division</h4>
            <div id="Division">
                <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="hidden" value="N" name="Accouting"><input value="hhhhhhhhhhh" type="checkbox" name="Accouting" id="Accouting">Accouting</label></div><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="hidden" value="N" name="Finance"><input value="hhhhhhhhhhh" type="checkbox" name="Finance" id="Finance">Finance</label></div><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="hidden" value="N" name="Insurance"><input value="hhhhhhhhhhh" type="checkbox" name="Insurance" id="Insurance">Insurance</label></div><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="hidden" value="N" name="HR training"><input value="hhhhhhhhhhh" type="checkbox" name="HR training" id="HR_training">HR training</label></div><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="hidden" value="N" name="information Technology"><input value="hhhhhhhhhhh" type="checkbox" name="information Technology" id="information_Technology">information Technology</label></div>            </div>
                        <hr>

             <h4>Location</h4>
             <div id="Location">
                <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="hidden" value="N" name="Lebanon"><input value="hhhhhhhhhhh" type="checkbox" name="Lebanon" id="Lebanon">Lebanon</label></div><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="hidden" value="N" name="UAE"><input value="hhhhhhhhhhh" type="checkbox" name="UAE" id="UAE">UAE</label></div><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="hidden" value="N" name="Saudi Arabia"><input value="hhhhhhhhhhh" type="checkbox" name="Saudi Arabia" id="Saudi_Arabia">Saudi Arabia</label></div><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="hidden" value="N" name="United Kingdom"><input value="hhhhhhhhhhh" type="checkbox" name="United Kingdom" id="United_Kingdom">United Kingdom</label></div><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="hidden" value="N" name="United States"><input value="hhhhhhhhhhh" type="checkbox" name="United States" id="United_States">United States</label></div><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="hidden" value="N" name="Eygpt"><input value="hhhhhhhhhhh" type="checkbox" name="Eygpt" id="Eygpt">Eygpt</label></div><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="hidden" value="N" name="mohammad"><input value="hhhhhhhhhhh" type="checkbox" name="mohammad" id="mohammad">mohammad</label></div><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="hidden" value="N" name="hiiiiiiii"><input value="hhhhhhhhhhh" type="checkbox" name="hiiiiiiii" id="hiiiiiiii">hiiiiiiii</label></div><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="hidden" value="N" name="bvbvbvbvbv"><input value="hhhhhhhhhhh" type="checkbox" name="bvbvbvbvbv" id="bvbvbvbvbv">bvbvbvbvbv</label></div><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="hidden" value="N" name="tststststststs"><input value="hhhhhhhhhhh" type="checkbox" name="tststststststs" id="tststststststs">tststststststs</label></div>             </div>
                         <hr>

             <h4>Status</h4>

            <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="hidden" value="N" name="Permanent"><input value="hhhhhhhhhhh" type="checkbox" name="Permanent" id="Permanent">  Permanent</label></div>
            <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="hidden" value="N" name="Temporary"><input value="hhhhhhhhhhh" type="checkbox" name="Temporary" id="Temporary">  Temporary</label></div>

            <hr>

              <h4>Hours</h4>

            <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="hidden" value="N" name="FullTime"><input value="hhhhhhhhhhh" type="checkbox" name="FullTime" id="FullTime"> Full-Time</label></div>
            <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="hidden" value="N" name="PartTime"><input value="hhhhhhhhhhh" type="checkbox" name="PartTime" id="PartTime"> Part-Time</label></div>
            <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="hidden" value="N" name="Flexible"><input value="hhhhhhhhhhh" type="checkbox" name="Flexible" id="Flexible"> Flexible</label></div>

            <hr>

<h4>Salary</h4>
<div id="Salary">

    <select class="form-control" name="s" id="s">
<option value="">Select salary</option>
<option value="1000$">1000$</option>
<option value="2000$">2000$</option>
<option value="3000$">3000$</option>
<option value="4000$">4000$</option>
<option value="5000$">5000$</option>
<option value="6000$">6000$</option>
<option value="7000$">7000$</option>
<option value="8000$">8000$</option>
<option value="9000$">9000$</option>
</select>                
             </div>
            <input type="submit" name="yt0" value="Search" id="yt0">                      </div>
                  </div><!-- /.blog-sidebar -->
```

why the checkboxes are always posted to the action? and why thier values always is 1?

Comment: How about also showing how this code is rendered in the browser source?

Comment: @Sparky in the browser source the checkboxes values are assigned correctly

Comment: Please show the rendered code anyway.  If it's doing what you claim, the code in the browser is ***directly*** responsible... not the raw code on the server.

Comment: note: I added `false, array('value'=>'hhhhhhhhhhh', 'uncheckValue'=>'N')` for all checkboxes

Comment: your closing `form` tag is missing from the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains `hidden` elements, but it's not clear why you think you need them:

```
<input type="hidden" value="N" name="HR training">
<input value="hhhhhhhhhhh" type="checkbox" name="HR training" id="HR_training">
```

Each of your `hidden` elements uses the exact same `name` as a `checkbox` element.

The post array uses the `name` attributes so if two different elements share the same `name`, your post array is not going to make much sense.  In other words, when you see "HR training" in the post array, how would you know if that's the `hidden` element or the `checkbox`?

**Each input should have a *unique* `name`**.  A "grouping" of radio/checkboxes is the exception and that's only because the group is considered as a single data point.

**Example**:

**Status: Permanent or Temporary?** (Note the use of `radio` buttons because the choice cannot be both.)

```
<input type="radio" name="status" value="permanent" />: Permanent
<input type="radio" name="status" value="temporary" />: Temporary
```

will give you the following results:

- if "Permanent" is checked, the data will contain `status=permanent`
- if "Temporary" is checked, the data will contain `status=temporary`
- if neither are checked, the data will not contain `status` at all

---

Meanwhile, this demo with your browser source code shows the problem you describe is not occuring.  None of your unchecked checkboxes are part of the serialized array.

http://jsfiddle.net/mhpVm/1/

Comment: the hidden elements can be removed by removing the `uncheckvalue` from the array, but why the posting value is always 1 ????

Comment: @user2101939, from the code you've shown, that is impossible:  http://jsfiddle.net/mhpVm/1/  ~  Please show enough code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: what a big failure ??? I didn't notice that I assigned `isset($_POST[''])` to the variable instead of `$_POST['']`, therefore the 1 is coming from the boolean return of `isset()` function